# Internally used functions in TypeScript library

Tags: typescript, node-modules

When I declare, define, and use a function inside a TypeScript node style library and then use the library from e.g. an angular project, the code fails in the browser, claiming that the function was not defined.

When I also use it directly from the code consuming the library, it is included in the resulting bundle.

If I don't do that, though, it's missing from the bundle, resulting in this error.

is there a way to declare inside a library that functions that are used internally are important and should be included in bundles?

Making the function a static method of a class doesn't work because I need to forward declare it in order to avoid a circular dependency, which is not possible for static methods.

The function inside "superclassDeserialization.ts":

```
export function createDesktopToCompanionEventFromStream(stream: InputStream): DesktopToCompanionEvent
{
    let subtypeId = Serializer.readSubtypeId(stream);
    switch(subtypeId)
    {
    case 1:
        return CodePointDesktopToCompanionEvent.createFromStreamAfterIdentification(stream);
    default:
        throw new RangeError("Unknown subtype ID for abstract struct companion.DesktopToCompanionEvent: " + subtypeId);
    }
}
```

The internal call from a static method of DesktopToCompanionEvent:

```
public static createFromStreamAfterIdentification(stream: InputStream): DesktopToCompanionEvent
{
    return createDesktopToCompanionEventFromStream(stream);
}
```

All of index.ts:

```
export { CompanionToDesktopEvent } from './CompanionToDesktopEvent';
export { DigitCompanionToDesktopEvent } from './DigitCompanionToDesktopEvent';
export { DrawingCompanionToDesktopEvent } from './DrawingCompanionToDesktopEvent';
export { DesktopToCompanionEvent } from './DesktopToCompanionEvent';
export { CodePointDesktopToCompanionEvent } from './CodePointDesktopToCompanionEvent';
export { BaseData } from './BaseData';
export { ExtraData } from './ExtraData';
export { Mode } from './Mode';
export * from './superclassDeserialization'
```

Comment: Do you correctly use `export` ? Please show your code.

Comment: Code now included.

Comment: The function is called from a static method of DesktopToCompanionEvent.